# Use ansi escape sequences to create a border between input and output

Tags: node.js, readline, ansi-escape

I am writing an app with streaming text output that needs to have an input area fixed to the bottom of the screen.

I am using `node:readline` and `ansi-escapes` and I just cannot figure out how to seperate the output from the input.

everything I try creates a mess of the output overwriting the prompt, or the border.

Here is my desired output:

```bash
1: 60e8cfe8-39b8-4fa7-9655-21d2157b1046
2: c5d5c922-b101-4d4b-aa49-54fe4633d6ef
3: 07080473-3f69-48cf-b0c6-de705423c1a6
4: 8ab3d8e7-37f5-48ad-9c55-3f21994de927
5: 8df28be4-011c-461b-9dda-973295ce2f9d
6: a4cdbc06-4b72-4df5-8c89-d43f15032f08
7: bc4f5c33-f138-4a5c-84fb-eaa2e7c9242b
----------------------------------------------------
> my input prompt here
```

Comment: with this: [https://www.npmjs.com/package/ansi-escapes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ansi-escapes) -- it lacks some way to control scrolling margins.  Without that, this simple application can't be done - simply.

Comment: Hey @ThomasDickey thanks for that. I have attempted some solutions and keep running in to issues where typing in the prompt resets the position of the output. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you could do this by modifying the ansi-escapes package to support scrolling margins, and switch the margins between the two sections of the screen as updates are needed -- leaving them normally confining the input area (caveat: scrolling margins can only be as small as 2 lines).  The save/restore cursor features in the existing package would be helpful when you do this.